# Spring Roo, Hibernate generates unnecessary foreign key for the primary key column

Tags: hibernate, spring-roo

I'm new to spring mvc, roo and hibernate. I'm using Oracle XE 10g database.

I've created new entity using Roo.

```
entity --class Opcina
field string --fieldName Naziv
field reference --fieldName Entitet --type ~.domain.Entitet
```

Generated java class is bellow:

```
import org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
import randb.domain.Entitet;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Opcina {

    private String Naziv;

    @ManyToOne
    private Entitet Entitet;
}
```

Generated table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."OPCINA"
  (
    "ID"      NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "NAZIV"   VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
    "VERSION" NUMBER(10,0),
    "ENTITET" NUMBER(19,0),
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FKC3C2CDFACAB9A04E" FOREIGN KEY ("ID") REFERENCES "TEST"."OPCINA" ("ID") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FKC3C2CDFA1A1F0EF1" FOREIGN KEY ("ENTITET") REFERENCES "TEST"."ENTITET" ("ID") ENABLE
  );
```

What is the purpose of

CONSTRAINT "FKC3C2CDFACAB9A04E" FOREIGN KEY ("ID") REFERENCES "TEST"."OPCINA" ("ID") ENABLE,

constraint, and why is it generated? (How can I avoid it?)

Comment: This behavior has nothing to do with Roo or Spring MVC, it is only related to JPA/Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have switched over to `Entitet` by accident during your Roo session. Be explicit with the target class:

```
field reference --fieldName Entitet --type ~.domain.Entitet --class ~.domain.Opcina
```

Or switch focus first:

```
focus --class ~.domain.Opcina
field reference --fieldName Entitet --type ~.domain.Entitet
```

Comment: since I'm not using Sprig Roo anymore (switched to PHP/Yii), I'm gonna mark your answer as correct one